# higher order function javascripts

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to understand better and start coding JS with higher order functions. Below is just a practice I'm doing, and I want to output an array of numbers * 2.

```
function each(collection, callback) {
  for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    callback(collection[i]);
    }
}

function isNumber(item) {

  var arr = [];
    if(typeof item === "number") {
      arr.push(item * 2);
    }

  return arr;
}

each([1, 2, 3, 4, "String"], isNumber);
```

from my understanding, when each() function is invoked with array and isNumber argument, it runs through function each. When each function is invoked, it calls back isNumber function with array[i], then isNumber function with that array[i] is invoked and if the type of the array[i] is a number, it pushes that number * 2 to an array. The output I'm expecting is

```
[2, 4, 6, 8] since "String" is not a number it never got pushed into the array.
```

Am I not understanding this correctly? When I try to log this code, no output shows.

Comment: Your array is redefined as an empty array each time `isNumber` is called.

Comment: Scope.  Your `var arr` is scoped to only the isNumber function, so there's a new array every time `isNumber()` is called.   Return value - at no point do you look at the value returned by isNumber.

Comment: You never do anything with the result of `isNumber`, which has the wrong signature anyway - it only has one item to deal with and should return true or false per the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
// Let's call this what it is
function getNumbersFromArray(collection, callback) {
    var arr = [],
        i = 0;

    for (; i < collection.length; i++) {
        // Check if isNumber and do mutliplication here
        if (callback(collection[i])) {
            arr.push(item * 2);
        }
    }

    return arr;
}

// Make isNumber actually return a boolean
function isNumber(item) {
    return typeof item === "number";
}

// call console.log()
console.log(getNumbersFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4, "String"], isNumber));
```

Answer (score 2):

no output is showing because neither of your functions return anything.

here, i'd have your callback just apply the multiplication and return that value, then push to an array in your each function

```
function each(collection, callback) {
  var arr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      var result = callback(collection[i])
      if (typeof result !== 'undefined') {
        arr.push(callback(collection[i]));
      }
    }
  return arr
}

function isNumber(item) {
    if (typeof item === "number") {
      return item * 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: `isNumber` returning a non-boolean is questionable.

Comment: i can edit it in, but is it best practice to fix every issue in a post or just get the OP to understand the issue originally asked? i feel like trying to correct every tiny issue would pollute answers so much it would begin distracting from the actual question

Comment: @PhilVarg It's never best practice to write code that is clearly not doing what it says it should do, the `each` function is actually a `map`. Please don't encourage people to treat each as map, they are different. It will take a few more lines, but you should explain to the OP that there is a peripheral issue with their question. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37861917/227299