# Higher order functions returning anything but a non-boolean is questionable. Why?

Tags: javascript, boolean, higher-order-functions

```
function each(collection, callback) {
  var arr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      var result = callback(collection[i])
      if (typeof result !== 'undefined') {
        arr.push(callback(collection[i]));
      }
    }
  return arr
}

function isNumber(item) {
    if (typeof item === "number") {
      return item * 2;
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand higher order functions. The above works, but is apparently not best practice to return a value with `isNumber`. I have been told that a Boolean value should be returned. Why? It works.

**Update:**
It appears to be because of the function name! Thanks everyone I just thought there might be some technical reason

Comment: Where did this warning come from?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's just a case of your naming. `isNumber` is almost question-like, where the answer would be yes/no, or a `boolean`. Your code would almost read like: *isNumber(5) == 10*, which just reads wrong. I also don't see the relevance of the `each` function within the context of this question at all.

Comment: @JuanMendes I wasn't told personally (just put that for simplification) In this example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169722/higher-order-function-javascripts?rq=1 . Thanks!

Comment: Functions beginning with `is` are always going to carry the expectation of a boolean result, something either *is* or *isn't*.

Comment: Why should a function called `isNumber(item)` double the number? Shouldn't a function that doubles a number be called `doubleNumber` or `multiplyNumberByTwo` or something that wouldn't surprise another programmer?

Comment: Why in the world you call the poor callback twice. You already have it's result assigned to `result`.

Comment: @redu Thanks for your input. I found this code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169722/higher-order-function-javascripts?rq=1 . I'm trying to understand higher order functions and just wanted to clarify the boolean point, incase it was anything important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a function is called `isNumber`, it should return a boolean.

Also, your each function is a `map` not an `each`. In that case your code should probably look like.

```
function flatMap(collection, callback) {
  var arr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      var result = callback(collection[i])
      if (typeof result !== 'undefined') {
        arr.push(callback(collection[i]));
      }
    }
  return arr;
}

function times2(item) {
    if (typeof item === "number") {
      return item * 2;
    }
    return item;
}

map([1,2,3,"hello"], times2);
```

If you wanted iteration that can be stopped, then it would look like

```
function iterate(collection, callback) {
  for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    var result = callback(collection[i])
    if (typeof result === false) {
      return;
    }
  }
}

function doSomethingAndStopIfNotANumber(item) {
   console.log(item);
   return typeof item == "number";
}

iterate([1,2,3, "hello", 4, 5], doSomethingAndStopIfNotANumber);
```

Note that [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not allow you to stop iteration by returning false, for that you'd need to misuse [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) (because that function returns a boolean, so it's just a semantic problem, not like map where you build an array and throw it away) or write a function like I did above.

Comment: What is the difference between each and map?

Comment: Thank-you . I thought the answer would be more complicated than that! It's not my code, I found it on this site in another question, I'm trying to understand about higher order functions and wanted to clarify this point. Thanks for your time! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169722/higher-order-function-javascripts?rq=1

Comment: FWIW, since your `map` function will only push the result of the callback if it's defined, I'd say it's more like `flatMap` instead.  I think it's an important invariant that `map` preserves the size of the collection.

Comment: `map` is for when you want to transform each item of an array and return a new array. `each` is when you just want to do something to each item, but don't want a new array with the "mapped" result. Using `map` when you mean `each` means that an array will be created, modified and then thrown away.